# JavaScript function toggle when clicking outside element

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to build a scientific calculator app but am getting hung up on the 2nd function. I want to be able to click the 2nd button, trigger button values to alter, and then when any other button is clicked toggle the 2nd function back off. I have accomplished everything but toggling the second function when I click outside of 2nd element.

I am generating the "buttons" using an html table layout with the 2nd button being a  element. I want to toggle it back off when any other  element is clicked. As suggested I have now added some code but not in its entirety (I have removed what hopefully is fluff) as it is quite long.

[image: calculator example]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calc.css">
<script src="calc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p id=myPara></p>
<p id=myAns>0</p>
<table>
<tr id="inputFieldrow">
    <td class="inputField" colspan=5><input id=result readonly></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td onclick="shiftFn(1)" id="shiftBtn">2nd</td>
    <td class="blueButton" id="modeBtn">mode</td>
    <td class="blueButton" onclick="del()" id="deleteBtn">delete</td>
    <td class="noBorder"></td>
    <td class="noBorder"></td>
</tr>

 <tr>
     <td class="blueButton" onclick="log(1)" id="logBtn">log</td>
     <td class="badButton" id="prbBtn">prb</td>
     <td class="badButton" id="dataBtn">data</td>
     <td class="noBorder"></td>
     <td class="noBorder"></td>
</tr>
```

and JavaScript

```
function shiftFn(state) {
var Btnshift = document.getElementById("shiftBtn"),
    Btnmode = document.getElementById("modeBtn"),
    Btndelete = document.getElementById("deleteBtn"),
    Btnlog = document.getElementById("logBtn");

if (state === 1) {
    Btnshift.setAttribute("onclick", "shiftFn(0)");
    Btnshift.style.backgroundColor = "orange";

    Btnmode.innerHTML = "quit";
    Btndelete.innerHTML = "insert";

    Btnlog.innerHTML = "10<sup>x</sup>";


} else {
    Btnshift.setAttribute("onclick", "shiftFn(1)");
    Btnshift.style.backgroundColor = "#A3D88A";


    Btnmode.innerHTML = "mode";
    Btndelete.innerHTML = "delete";

    Btnlog.innerHTML = "log";
    Btnlog.setAttribute("onclick", "log(1)");
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code? You could create an untoggle function that you invoke every time a secondary function is called

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to go about this and without seeing a sample of your code it's somewhat hard to give you the best advice.

Comment: ok I have added the code as requested. Thanks.